# Angular web component does not work as it should

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-elements

I've created a simple Angular 6 project due to I want to create a web component. ([GitHub URL](https://github.com/CSantosM/angular-elements-demo.git)). You can clone the repo with `git clone https://github.com/CSantosM/angular-elements-demo.git`.

I have followed [this tutorial](https://codingthesmartway.com/angular-elements-a-practical-introduction-to-web-components-with-angular-6/) and I have create the web component with success. However, when I test this web component in another application with JavaScript it doesn't work completelly.

The problem is the `*ngIf="display"` of the `button.component.ts` html [github code](https://github.com/CSantosM/angular-elements-demo/blob/37b8cfecc3fba13ad3d5226f7e126f28b9c07a5e/src/app/button/button.component.ts#L6):

```
<div  *ngIf="display">
 <h3>Hello {{_userName}}</h3>
 <div class="button-row">
   <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="toggleBlue()">
   <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon" 
      matTooltip="Like">favorite</mat-icon>
   </button>
 </div>
 <mat-icon *ngIf="blue">alarm</mat-icon>
</div>
```

Inserting the web component in my JavaScript app [located here](https://github.com/CSantosM/angular-elements-demo/tree/master/elements) and **changing the input web component dynamically**, the button doesn't work as it should.

My index.html is ([github code](https://github.com/CSantosM/angular-elements-demo/blob/master/elements/index.html)):

```
<div id="main" style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>Insert your name</h1>
    <form onsubmit="sendName(); return false" style="padding: 80px; margin: auto">
        <p>
            <label>User:</label>
            <input type="text" id="user" value="User1" required>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="JOIN">
        </p>
    </form>
</div>

<custom-button name=""></custom-button>

<!-- WebComponent JS -->
<script type='application/javascript' src='custom-button.js'></script>
<!-- WebComponent JS -->

<script>

    function sendName() {

        var user = document.getElementById('user').value;
        var ov = document.querySelector('custom-button');
        ov.userName = user;
    }

</script>
```

When I press the button of this app, the `sendName()` function is called and the  `userName input` changes, the **angular variable** named `display` changes to **true** and the web component can be seen. ([github code](https://github.com/CSantosM/angular-elements-demo/blob/37b8cfecc3fba13ad3d5226f7e126f28b9c07a5e/src/app/button/button.component.ts#L32))

If I don't include the `display` variable, the web component works as it should.

**Here you can see the behavior:**

[image]

Is a known error by Angular? Why with a simple *ngIf, the web component doesn't work fine? How can resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should work with *ngIf I was able to use *ngIf and call a service, and show content only if service was successful. Also, you said when you hit the button the component displays, since it's true. Isn't that intended use?

Comment: The component is displays but the funcionality doesn't work as it should. You can test the component cloning the repo and execute http-server inside of elements folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I published the issue in angular github repo and the workaround they provide me is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24732)